# Unity Crashes Location.Service () In Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, gps, location

I am using unity v5.5.3f1. And I am working on Unity Location.Service() to get user's GPS co-ordinates. I use the Code Snippet in the Unity Manual to use the GPS in unity. But when I run this code snippet in the Android Device, It crashes the Application. I referred and worked with some solution that are suggested in google, but didn't work. Even the Patches delivered by Unity Dev Team. So Can somebody help to solve this out, what my purpose is to use GPS and get the Location Co-ordinates.

References :

To use GPS :-  [unity location Service](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html)

To Patch : [To use the Patch, but version error occurred, 5.5.3f1 is missing here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-location-app-crashes-due-to-error-jstring-has-wrong-type-android-dot-location-dot-location)

Note : using the Unity Version 5.5.3f1 on Windows 10 Platform, Testing on Android 4.1

Comment: This bug has been fixed  in Unity 5.6.0

Comment: @Programmer I already saw that in 5.6.0 this has been fixed, but my case is I there I have to rebuild the whole project in 5.6.0 as I got some library crashes when I shift to higher version. cuz I have to rebuild the project when I shifted to 5.4 to 5.5 ! So is there any kind of particular way that was used in 5.5.3f, to solve GPS crash thing, I couldn't find compatible patch for 5.5.3f1 too